# removing unnecessary line breaks using regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

When I view the source of html page, i find many instances of new line/line breaks and one such example is:

```
<p>Q
239 OF 
1999</p>
```

Ideally it should be

```
<p>Q 239 OF 1999</p>
```

As a result of this when I do pattern search the search and replace fails.
I tried following

```
/[\n\r]/
```

but this didn't do anything.
How can this be fixed using preg_replace?

Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj -- Nope. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you include the code you're using?

The following appears to work:

`preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "", $input);`

Comment: Ok when I tried this globally, it worked. When I was splitting the document into two strings and then trying to run this on one part, it simply wouldn't work. Serves my purpose.